# R- Will modifications on data be applied if I force R to stop the loop?

Tags: r

I ran a code but it's taking ages to be done, and I really need to close the laptop, but I was wondering if I force R to stop, will it take into account the modifications that it already ran?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect this to be dependent on how you set up your analysis. I just ran the code in the example below, and stopped running it midway through. My vector had been partially updated. Obviously, if you exit out of R without saving your workspace your progress will be lost.

```
vec <- 1:500
for(i in vec) {
  for(j in c(1:500)) { factorial(j) } # Add delay
  vec[i] <-  0                        # Update vector
}

# Force the code to stop running mid loop (In R Studio I press the stop button)

# Show the result
plot(vec)
```

[image]